# How can i specify the dns servers when terrafrorm uses aws_route53_zone

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, terraform

When terraform runs the following, it apparently picks random NS servers:

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "example.com" {
  name = "example.com"
}
```

The problem with this is that the registered domain that I have in AWS already has specified NS servers. Is there a way to specify the NS servers this resource uses - or maybe change the hosted domain's NS servers to what is picked when the zone is created?

Comment: Are you saying you already have a Route53 zone for your domain? If that's the case you just need to use `terraform import` to bring the zone into your state so that Terraform can manage it.

Comment: No I'm saying I have a registered domain with AWS that I'm using terraform to create a zone with.

Comment: A domain doesn't have name servers. If you bought a domain through AWS they normally prompt you if you want to create a zone at the same time.

Comment: There's a place to add your dns servers under Registered Domains > exmaple.com on the right side of the aws panel. These servers do not get updated when terraform creates a new zone... the zone gets a bunch of random NS servers showing up in Hosted Zones  that never match what's in the Registered Domains settings. I need a way to make sure these sync up.

Comment: So you bought a domain but didn't create the zone at the same time? In that case you should have an option to edit your name servers to be whatever you want (doesn't even have to be Route53) in the AWS console. Route53 does allow you to create reusable delegation sets to share name servers between zones but you still need to have a zone with those in first.

Comment: I have the option to set them to what is used by the zone created by terraform, (manually) yes. I'd like terraform to do that editing.

Comment: I don't think AWS exposes an API for managing the name servers there. And if it does then Terraform can't control it (yet). You'll need to manually set the domain to be linked to some name servers that do exist and from there you could use reusable delegation sets to share the same name servers across zones.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR the [`UpdateDomainNameservers`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_domains_UpdateDomainNameservers.html) action seems to be the interface to modify the associated nameservers for a registered domain... not that it helps.

Comment: Messing around with the reusable delegation sets seems to be a goos way to solve this... passing the set id to the aws_route53_zone gets me about what I need.

Comment: @TyMac please post your solution.

Comment: @demisx my solution is to create the delegation id separately and then feed it as a var to aws_route53_zone with delegation_set_id.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new zone, AWS generates the Name server list for you. Using this example from Terraform.

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "dev" {
  name = "dev.example.com"

  tags {
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "dev-ns" {
  zone_id = "${aws_route53_zone.main.zone_id}"
  name    = "dev.example.com"
  type    = "NS"
  ttl     = "30"

  records = [
    "${aws_route53_zone.dev.name_servers.0}",
    "${aws_route53_zone.dev.name_servers.1}",
    "${aws_route53_zone.dev.name_servers.2}",
    "${aws_route53_zone.dev.name_servers.3}",
  ]
}
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route53_zone.html

API returns a Delegation Set after the call to Create Zone.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_CreateHostedZone.html#API_CreateHostedZone_ResponseSyntax

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to specify DNS servers but I would imagine that AWS is allocating servers based on availability, load etc... so you may want to think hard about baking these configs in.

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "primary-ns" {
  zone_id = "${aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id}"
  name    = "www.bacon.rocks"
  type = "NS"
  ttl = "172800"
  records = ["ns-869.awsdns-44.net","ns-1237.awsdns-26.org","ns-1846.awsdns-38.co.uk","ns-325.awsdns-40.com"]
}
```

or something along those lines

Comment: This will create the NS record, yeah- but it won't actually set the name server values for the zone. I think it might be out of one's control...